# Derivative of trig function (l'hopital's rule)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Find: $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^26x}{\sin^27x} $$

My answer was :
$$ \frac{2\sin6x \cdot \cos6x}{2\sin7x \cdot \cos7x} $$

When I took the derivative of the numerator and denominator I got this
$$ \frac{\cos6x \cdot 6 \cdot \cos6x + \sin6x \cdot -\sin6x \cdot 6}{\cos7x \cdot 7 \cdot \cos7x + \sin7x \cdot -\sin7x \cdot 7} $$

and the final answer was: $ \frac{6}{7} $. The answer in the book is: $ \frac{36}{49} $.

So what am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to multiply with $6$ and $7$ above and below. You have $f(g(h(x)))'$, where $f(t)=t^2$, $g(t)=\sin t$ and $h(t)=n t$, where $n$ is $6$ and $7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substitute more carefully. You should have a six in the numerator and a seven in the denominator, in the first step.
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin^2{kx} = 2 \sin{kx} \cos{kx} \cdot k$$

Answer (score 1):

Usin L'Hospital twice
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^26x}{\sin^27x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{12\sin6x\cos6x}{14\sin7x\cos7x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6(\sin6x\cos6x)'}{7(\sin7x\cos7x)'}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6(6\cos6x-6\sin6x)}{7(7\cos7x-7\sin7x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{36(\cos6x-\sin6x)}{49(\cos7x-\sin7x)}=\frac{36}{49}$$

Comment: can you explain how do you got the derivative of $(sin6xcos6x)$. when i did it i got $cos6x\cdot6\cdot cos6x+sin6x\cdot(-sin6x\cdot6)$

Answer (score 0):

Using

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin kx}{kx}=1\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\text{we get that}:$$

$$\frac{\sin^26x}{\sin^27x}=\frac{36}{49}\left(\frac{\sin6x}{6x}\right)^2\left(\frac{7x}{\sin^27x}\right)^2\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac{36}{49}\cdot 1^2\cdot1^2=\frac{36}{49}$$

No derivatives used/needed...

Answer (score 0):

$\sin t\to t$ when $t\to0$ . In our case, $t_1=6x$, and $t_2=7x$. Our limit becomes $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(6x)}{\sin^2(7x)}=$ $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(6x)^2}{(7x)^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{36x^2}{49x^2}=\frac{36}{49}$ . QED.